# How to export .gltf file with wave modifier animation?

Tags: surface-deform

I was trying to create a fish animation in blender
I have come across on this YT tutorial where there is a plane that have a wave modifier on it
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWdFRqlnmUM&ab_channel=BlenderStudy). The fish model then have a surface deform modifier that is bind into the plane. In the blender the animation goes well, but after exporting it into gltf file the animation is gone.

I am new to blender, can someone please help me :(, I would really appreciate it.

[image]